# Unity UI : How to reenable a dropdown after its panel was deactivated and then reactivated?

Tags: unity-game-engine, drop-down-menu

I am new to Unity, so this is probably a dumb question but here goes:
I have a Unity app; it has several scenes.  One of those scenes has a Canvas upon which there are several overlapping Panels.  On one of the Panels (PanelA), there is a Dropdown.  When the app first runs PanelA is active and on top by default and the dropdown works fine.  But after I deactivate PanelA with a C# call to

```
panelA.SetActive(false);// hides the panel
```

and then later reactivate it like so:

```
panelA.SetActive(true); // redisplays the panel
```

The dropdown no longer displays its list of option when clicked on.  The dropdown is still there and still shows its first option "None" and when clicked on the drop-down changes color to indicate that it was touched, but the dropdown does not drop down its list of options.
What am I missing?  Why doesn't the dropdown show the list of options?
Thanks

Windows 10 Pro v1709, unity 2017.1.1f1 Personal

My hierarchy is like so, PanelB is the panel that gets set active after PanelA is inactivated:
[image]

The script called when the dropdowns option is selected is called like so in Start():

```
PickDropDown.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate {
            myDropdownValueChangedHandler(PickDropDown);
        });
```

and the called function is:

```
    private void myDropdownValueChangedHandler(Dropdown target) {
        Debug.Log("selected: "+target.value);
        stage = 0;

        currentval = PickDropDown.options [PickDropDown.value].text;
        advice.text = "";
        title.text = currentval;
        if (currentval != NONE) {
            advice.text = "You chose to do  "+currentval;
            nextVal();
        }
    }

    void newVal(){
        Debug.Log("newVal  " );

        PanelA.SetActive (true);
        PanelB.SetActive (false);
        Debug.Log("options  count="+ PickDropDown.options.Count );
    }

    void nextVal(){
        Debug.Log("nextSet  " );
        PanelB.SetActive (true);
        /*** next line shows the answer to my problem - from killer_mech **/   
        Destroy(PickDropDown.transform.Find("Dropdown List").gameObject);
        /***************************************************************/
        PanelA.SetActive (false);
    }
```

Comment: Haven't observed this behavior before myself, but one thing you can do instead (and is a cheap optimization) is to break things into multiple canvases and then just simply...disable the canvas component (so it doesn't render) rather than disabling the whole GO.

Comment: I suspect that the "panelA" is on top of the dropdown. Post screenshot of your Hierarchy. This might shed some light on what's going on.

Comment: @Draco18s - I tried that first and had the same problem, I had hoped using panels would fix it.

Comment: @Programmer - I have now included the screenshot above.

Comment: Did you checked if the dropdown retains its values after turning on and off. I would recommend to check the places where you are adding manually the values. It would be nice to have a look at the script also.

Comment: @killer_mech -  I only add the options in the inspector under Options. What part of the script might be relevant - all it does is call SetActive(T/F) on the panels.  After the dropdown reappears I check the number of options and the count is still 6; ie Debug.Log("options  count="+PickDropDown.options.Count );  Also the option displayed is still the last one I selected.

Comment: @killer_mech - added some code to post above.

Comment: I see.  I currently tried with one panel and Dropdown under which it worked properly and showed the values when i toggled the state. Can you try again producing the same result in another project?.

Comment: @Programmer - the Pos Z of the PanelA is 0, same as the Pick Drop Down an its subcomponents.  What did you mean by - the "panelA" is on top of the dropdown?  Also when I click in it the color changes indicating that it received the click.

Comment: What I meant by panelA is the Object the "panelA" variable is referencing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug in unity. I can reproduce this now. This is happening because Unity is creating a game Object called "**Dropdown List**" inside dropdown which should get destroyed after the closing. But I have noticed a slight delay is happening while destroying(I used editor debug mode for this). When you set the game object active flag as false, it somehow stops the destroy object and results in object **Dropdown List** staying there so next time when you try to interact with it the object will still present. You will also notice a white box below the Dropdown list after this which indicates the dropdown list still is present.

For the solution what I did was just before I was about to turn my gameobject off I used

**`Destroy(PickDropDown.transform.Find("Dropdown List").gameObject);`**

Destroying this object solves the problem. I know this is not a good way to do it, but I checked whether any references to options are destroyed while destroying this which resulted in no error for me. And Dropdown creates new "**Dropdown List**" gameobject. So it is safe to assume that destroying is OK. Well not sure if any other good solution for this is out there but for now you can use this.

---

Note: I have tested this bug with Panel, Empty Gameobject as parent and finally with Dropdown

[image]
[image]

[image]

This shows what is happening inside the drop-down. 1) During No popup 2) During Open 3)After setactive off before the child is destroyed.

Comment: Thanks! I had tried something like that before as there was a similar bug reported but it didn't work then because the way I coded it was wrong - I didn't understand the Find parameter and used my object name or something instead of just "Dropdown List".  Your explanation cleared that up.